# alternative for jqXhr.abort()

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I need to selectively abort some ajax requests.

In fact I do something like a search. When the user changes the search term the result for all previous searches don't matter to me any more. So I want to cancel all callbacks for previous calls.

I read jquery documentation and found jqHhr.abort() is possible but still there for backward compatibility. Does this mean it will become deprecated or is the abort function the correct way?
How to achieve this otherwise?

Comment: Backward compatibility with `XMLHttpRequest`. Then don't worry, `xhr.abort()` is the way to do it through jQuery :)

Comment: ah, ok, thanks
so I misunderstood documentation